# EF 5: Attach an object without a primary key or id to update a column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have this code:

```
var user = new User { UserName = "whatever", LastLoginOn = DateTime.UtcNow };
_baseRepository.Context.Users.Attach(user);
_baseRepository.Context.Entry(user).Property(p => p.LastLoginOn).IsModified = true;
_baseRepository.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is I'm getting this error: `"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."`

When I use a UserId it works however I have to make a round trip to the database to get that ID. Is there a way to do the lookup by the user name?

**EDIT**

For a work around I've done this:

```
_baseRepository.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("UPDATE [dbo].[User] SET LastLoginDate = SYSUTCDATETIME() WHERE [UserName] = '{0}'", username));
```

But this isn't proper and it would be nice to know what the real answer would be.

Comment: I think your workaround is the only way. Ideally the PK would always be included in any request to modify an existing entity. Why is the id not available?

Comment: The ID is avilable but only if I go out to the database to grab it by the user name. I'm doing this on ASP.NET MVC 4 in both the Membership login and OAuth login